# how to get the elevation of each points(pixel) in image using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I am trying to get an elevation for each pixel in the image using image processing by python. My first try is by converting the image to grayscale and covert the 2d image to 3d image by using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
imageFile = 'D:\Books\Pav Man\PICS\pic (17) - Copy.png'
mat = imread(imageFile)

mat = mat[:,:,0] # get the first channel
#mat = mat - np.full_like(mat , mat.mean()) #Use this to get negative value
rows, cols = mat.shape
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(range(cols), range(rows)[::-1])

blurred = ndimage.gaussian_filter(mat, sigma=(5, 5), order=0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax.imshow(mat, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax.elev= 75
ax.plot_surface(xv, yv, mat)
ax = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax.imshow(blurred, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')
ax.elev= 75
ax.plot_surface(xv, yv, blurred)
plt.show()
```

The mat contains x,y,z values for each pixel, x = width coordinate , y = height coordinate , z = grayscale value that ranges from 0 to 1 but it does not include the real elevation.

The second try is by using depth data from 2 images as mentioned in the following link:
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html

But there is no clear way to estimate or predict the elevation of points in the image.
The following picture describes what I mean:

[click here to show picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRL3U.jpg)

My question is **how to get the elevation of each point in the image to create a topographic profile?**

Comment: I can't vote negative but you should read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).
You need to understand what's the problem you are trying to solve. There's no depth information stored in image.

Comment: This isn't converting 2D to 3D; you are just looking at one channel of the image, which is a color one.  BTW, in the future, you should post the image here, rather than link to an external one, so the question is self contained.

Comment: asylumax , I can't upload images to my post because I'm new here... I edit the code and I can show the blurred image and normal image and xyz coordinates ... E-soria I am new to image processing and if I'm wrong please guide me.